How to explode dxf block, pass a layer to a sub_entities and save with ezdxf
I am working on ezdxf v1.3.3. I am trying to explode all the INSERT from a file. I am running to a problem. When I explode the block, I want to give the sub_entities the layer of the block. When I check with the print in the terminal, it's working fine I guess... But in the end, when I open the dxf file no layer is attributed to the sub_entities.
Does someone have a clue, please?
import ezdxf

class tool_test:
    def __init__(self, dxf = str) -> None:
        self.name = dxf
        self.doc = ezdxf.readfile(self.name)
        self.msp = self.doc.modelspace()

    def all_blocks_2_polylines(self):
        while len(self.msp.query("INSERT")) != 0:
            for entity in self.msp:
                layer = entity.dxf.layer
                self.blocks_2_polylines(entity, layer) 
            self.doc.save()
    
    def blocks_2_polylines(self, entity, layer):
        explode = []
        if entity.dxftype() == 'INSERT':
            explode = entity.explode()
            for ent in explode:
                if hasattr(ent.dxf, 'layer'):
                    ent.dxf.layer = layer
                    print(f"Entity {ent.dxftype()} on layer {ent.dxf.layer}")         
        elif entity.dxftype() == 'HATCH':
            self.msp.delete_entity(entity)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dxf = 'your_path_here'
    print("start")
    my_tool = tool_test(dxf)
    my_tool.all_blocks_2_polylines()
    print("done")

I read the doc but I didn't find anything except "TODO", I also asked Chat GPT but it didn't come up with a better solution than mine. Finally, I tried to add sub_entities to a new file. It worked in most cases but I don't like this solution...

The Insert.explode() method returns an EntityQuery container, which provides descriptors for common DXF attributes: https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tasks/query.html#descriptors-for-dxf-attributes
explode = entity.explode()
explode.layer = layer

These descriptors ignore entities that do not support the corresponding DXF attribute.
